# How to have a URL With a Query String and Focuses on Element?

Tags: html, url

In the URL, you can focus on a particular element by appending a '#' and its id. For example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com?#footer
```

The code above will auto-focus you to the element with the id "footer".
Now what if I would like to include a query string along with it? Like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com?#footer&id=3
http://stackoverflow.com?&id=3#footer
http://stackoverflow.com?#footer+id=3
http://stackoverflow.com/#footer?id=3
```

None of those URLs above seem to work. What's the correct URL?

Comment: The query string starts with `?`, followed by the first `name=value` pair – only _additional_ `name=value` pairs are joined with (usually) an `&`. So `http://stackoverflow.com?id=3#footer` would correct; if that “doesn’t work” for you, then there’s something wrong with your application. Btw., pretty basic stuff …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com?id=3#footer
```

Everything after the `#` is client-side, which is why it comes last.

If this does not work, you would need to post more of your code, as the problem would then be with how you are handling the query string parameter and/or whether you have the anchor in your HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to completely separate them? My URL parser that gets the value of 'id' also includes '#footer' with it. Is it possible to separate it with & or / ?

Comment: In that case it would make sense to fix the issue in the parser than to use unconventional syntax.